# How can I customize the characters used to render whitespace in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know in VS Code you can set `editor.renderWhitespace` to `"all"` to render whitespace character such as space or tab. Is there any way I can change the symbols used? Thanks :)

I've been thinking about creating a font that changes `·` and `→`, but I only need them to be changed in the invisible characters, I'd like to keep my current font for `→` normally.

Comment: related: [Allow customizing whitespace characters #101013](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/101013)

Answer (score 1):

#### A solution using homemade font:

*Note: It work only for spaces (not for tab character)*

1. Create your homemade font with custom whitespace characters (you can use online tools like https://www.glyphrstudio.com/online/)
2. Install created font on your OS
3. Update VSCode settings in order to use your font and disable whitespace rendering:

```
"editor.renderWhitespace": "none"
"editor.fontFamily": "replaceWithYourCustomFontName, Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace"
```

---

**Result (using a font with little smiley as space):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See also the issue ticket [Allow customizing whitespace characters
#101013](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/101013). I'm not sure why it's closed, but as for actionable info at the time of this writing, if you want to customize those characters, I think you'll need to create a custom font that sets glyphs for those characters.

The glyphs / characters that VS Code uses for whitespace rendering can be found in the source code in src/vs/editor/common/viewLayout/viewLineRenderer.ts

[in the constructor](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/1.80.2/src/vs/editor/common/viewLayout/viewLineRenderer.ts#L121):

> ```js
> const wsmiddotDiff = Math.abs(wsmiddotWidth - spaceWidth);
> const middotDiff = Math.abs(middotWidth - spaceWidth);
> if (wsmiddotDiff < middotDiff) {
>   this.renderSpaceWidth = wsmiddotWidth;
>   this.renderSpaceCharCode = 0x2E31; // U+2E31 - WORD SEPARATOR MIDDLE DOT
> } else {
>   this.renderSpaceWidth = middotWidth;
>   this.renderSpaceCharCode = 0xB7; // U+00B7 - MIDDLE DOT
> }
> ```

and [in the `_renderLine` function](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/1.80.2/src/vs/editor/common/viewLayout/viewLineRenderer.ts#L1002):

> ```js
>   if (!canUseHalfwidthRightwardsArrow || charWidth > 1) {
>       sb.appendCharCode(0x2192); // RIGHTWARDS ARROW
>   } else {
>       sb.appendCharCode(0xFFEB); // HALFWIDTH RIGHTWARDS ARROW
>   }
>   for (let space = 2; space <= charWidth; space++) {
>       sb.appendCharCode(0xA0); // &nbsp;
>   }
>
> } else { // must be CharCode.Space
>   producedCharacters = 2;
>   charWidth = 1;
>
>   sb.appendCharCode(renderSpaceCharCode); // &middot; or word separator middle dot
>   sb.appendCharCode(0x200C); // ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER
> }
> ```

Those are the character codes you'll want to modify if you want to make a custom font to change them.