# Why is VS Code rendering Incorrect Glyph for space character?

Tags: visual-studio-code, fonts

I made a custom font using font forge and it works perfectly fine in every other text editor I try but VS code puts a different character instead of the standard space glyph.
[Example of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jesOg.png)

I've already checked to make sure other blank Unicode characters are not broken. Only space and no-break_space have this issue and exclusively in VS code.

As per comment suggestions:

- I checked with Extensions Disabled and it still happened
- After pressing space key debug returned

  ```
  2023-08-02 03:23:11.127 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
  2023-08-02 03:23:11.147 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving Space
  2023-08-02 03:23:11.148 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 6 keybinding entries, no when clauses matched the context.
  2023-08-02 03:23:11.148 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [], code: Space, keyCode: 32, key:  
  2023-08-02 03:23:11.148 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [], code: Space, keyCode: 10 ('Space')
  2023-08-02 03:23:11.149 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving Space
  2023-08-02 03:23:11.149 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 6 keybinding entries, no when clauses matched the context.
  ```
- Changing the render white space option only made it go from white to dark grey [grey characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOOfO.png)
- editor.fontFamily is set to the name of my custom font
- and no, this question post is not an Among Us joke- it's a serious question about a problem I'm facing. I just set every character I didn't have a graphic for to a character that looks like a crewmate from that game.

Comment: see also [Custom invisible character rendering in VSCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62007786/11107541). Please also tell us what your `editor.fontFamily` setting is set to.

Comment: what is your custom font? where can we download it? "_and no its not an among us joke. I just set every character I didn't have a graphic for to him._" What did you set the glyph for your ASCII space character to? Also, does this happen in any other application when you set the font in that application to your custom font?

Comment: @starball I've put it on my github https://github.com/Dob-The-Duilder/H32Font/ this font works in notepad and notepad++ it even works inside windows command prompt VScode is the only platform that seems to be having issues. Ive double checked with font views and made sure space is set to a blank character

Comment: @starball hey somehow with me changing nothing it started working between last night and now thanks for trying to help anyways

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the cause of this issue is that you just didn't set anything for the characters that VS Code uses to render whitespaces. As you explained, the character that you're seeing is the character that you set for your font to "fall back to" if you didn't provide anything else in particular for a specific character point. See [my answer to "How can I customize the characters used to render whitespace in VS Code?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76823765/11107541) for that list of characters that VS Code uses for rendering whitespace.